# How to add variable to array?

Tags: php

I have array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 0
            [month] => May
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1000000
            [month] => June
        )
)
```

I have variable like this : `$target = 3000000`

I want add the variable to array

So, the result like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 0
            [month] => May
            [target] => 3000000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1000000
            [month] => June
            [target] => 3000000
        )
)
```

Whether it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value){
    $myArray[$key]['target'] = $target;
}
print_r($myArray); // To print array
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521602/how-to-make-triangle-roll-up-with-php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  foreach($your_array as $k=>$v):
     $your_array[$k]['target'] = $target;
  endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to add the `target` Key to all the Sub-Arrays in the main array just like the one you posted you may do that with a Loop like this:

```
    <?php
        $target    = 3000000;
        $mainArray = array(
           array(
             'total' => 0,
             'month' => 'May',
           ),
           array(
             'total' => 1000000,
             'month' => 'June',
           ),
        );

        foreach($mainArray as $key=>&$subArrays){
            $subArrays['target'] = $target;
        }

        var_dump($mainArray);  //<== SHOULD CONTAIN THE ENTRY: target.

        //DUMPS
        array(
           array(
             'total' => 0,
             'month' => 'May',
             'target' => 3000000,
           ),
           array(
             'total' => 1000000,
             'month' => 'June',
             'target' => 3000000,
           ),
        );
```

Confirm the result [here](https://eval.in/605697).

Answer (score 0):

use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$target = ['target' => 3000000];

foreach ($array as &$item) {
     $item = array_merge($item, $target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always know the variable name, then you can do like below

```
$target = 3000000
foreach($array as $key => $val){
   $array[$key]['target'] = $target;//create new index "target" and assign the value
}
```

**Note:** `$array` is your current array

**The out put**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [total] => 0
        [month] => May
        [target] => 3000000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [total] => 1000000
        [month] => June
        [target] => 3000000
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler way., No need of extra array initialization.

foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    $value['target'] = 5000;
}

print_r($array);

Answer (score 0):

Php's array_map lets you apply a function to every element of an array.

```
<?php

$input = array
    (
        array
            (
                'total' => 0,
                'month' => 'May'
            ),
        array
            (
                'total' => 1000000,
                'month' => 'June'
            )
    );

$output = array_map
    (
        function($item) {
            $item['target'] = '3000000';
            return $item;
        },
        $input
    );

var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'total' => 0,
    'month' => 'May',
    'target' => '3000000',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'total' => 1000000,
    'month' => 'June',
    'target' => '3000000',
  ),
)
```